# How to use Data.Binary and System.IO.Handle

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to deserialize some data of type `T` from a `Handle` `h`. `T` has a `Binary` instance. There are two constraints:

1. The length of the serialized data is difficult to calculate in the serialized form.
2. There are additional data in `h` that are consumed by other parts of the code.

This makes it difficult to read the contents in as a (lazy or strict) `ByteString` and run `Get T` on the `ByteString`.

Is there a way to run `Get T` on a `Handle` directly?

Comment: The short but unpleasant answer is _no_. `Get` is [defined directly around lazy bytestrings](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.9.0.0/docs/src/Data-Binary-Get-Internal.html#Get). You can try defining/using a parsing monad transformer. Then you will have a notion of what it means to sequence reads from two different places. Unfortunately, that rules out `attoparsec` -  you are left with `parsec` (or its newer and better sibling `megaparsec`). What is you initial problem?

Comment: @Alec Thanks for your comment. This discussion and @Lazersmoke's answer made me realize that I really need to make sure `h` is used linearly. Otherwise, it may introduce subtle bugs that will be difficult to correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`hGetContents`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:hGetContents) to read all the data into a bytestring lazily, and deserialize that.

If other parts of your code need to access the handle after you use it, then you will need to manually read bytes from the handle until you are able to determine where the part you are interested in ends. (See the implementation if `hGetContents` for details) After that, you can stop reading bytes and pass the handle along to whstever part of your program needs it.

Note that it is probably a better design to have one location (thread?) in your code deserialize/parse from the handle and then diseminate the results, rather than passing around the handle itself. If you do this, you can use `hGetContents` and keep all your deserialization code in one place. You might also consider wrapping reading/writing handles into a monad transformer/free monad effect thingy if you use it a lot throughout your code.

Comment: Constraint 2 makes this difficult. Other parts of the code uses `h`. If I use `hGetContents`, does that make other parts of the code unable to get anything from `h`?